# Path not found in Python

Tags: python, path, pathlib

I have strange issue on environment where i have imported 'pathlib', it says Path is not defined after executing below command in terminal.

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> Path.cwd()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Path' is not defined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You need to import Path from pathlib

```
from pathlib import Path
Path.cwd()
```

Alternatively,

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path.cwd()
```